# Average time difference by rows with different column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have done some searching for similar question, but with no luck.
Sample table below.

```
ID |    MO   | Serial | PiID | Part_Number  |      Timestamp
 1 | F610320 |   1    |  QC1 |  4A130015    | 2017-05-10 09:55:28
 2 | F610320 |   2    |  QC1 |  4A130015    | 2017-05-10 10:12:54
 3 | F610320 |   3    |  QC1 |  4A130015    | 2017-05-10 10:19:47
 4 | F631323 |   1    |  QC2 |  4A110007B   | 2017-05-10 10:20:24
 5 | F631323 |   2    |  QC2 |  4A110007B   | 2017-05-10 10:21:50
 6 | F631323 |   3    |  QC3 |  4A110007B   | 2017-05-10 10:31:02
 7 | F631323 |   4    |  QC3 |  4A110007B   | 2017-05-10 10:31:02
```

and after the command
SELECT A.*, COUNT(A.MO) FROM datalog A GROUP BY A.MO, A.PiID

I want a column with average time. (distinct `MO` and `PiID`)

```
|    MO   | PiID | Part_Number  |COUNT(MO)|    average time
| F610320 |  QC1 |  4A130015    |    3    | (10:19:47 - 09:55:28)/3-1
| F631323 |  QC2 |  4A110007B   |    2    |avg time between row by MO and PiID
| F631323 |  QC3 |  4A110007B   |    2    |avg time between row by MO and PiID
```

Comment: Is it possible for a `MO` / `PiID` combination to have just one record?

Comment: I donno, somehow it works. :S
By the way, where did the other answer go?
Still trying the two differences tho...

Comment: It was removed by the Answerer.  Apparently they concluded either that their Answer was not worth fixing or that fixing it would have meant that their Answer would have ended up like the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While MySQL allows some weird combinations of columns between `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, the general rule for standard SQL is *"when using aggregation functions, all columns in your `SELECT` must be either aggregated or placed in `GROUP BY` too"*.

What you're trying to do then requires a query like this

```
select  MO, PiID, Part_Number,
        count(*) as CNT,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                      min(Timestamp),
                      max(Timestamp)
                     ) / (count(*) - 1) as Average_Time
from    datalog
group by MO, PiID, Part_Number
having  count(*) > 1
```

This will return the average time in seconds, but you can use different time units as well.

Note that calculating the average time difference requires at least two timestamps to be available, so I added that `HAVING` clause. Without that, `MO / PiID` combinations with only one row would cause a division by zero.

**Edit**

After thinking about it better, actually you don't need the HAVING clause, because if a `MO / PiID` combination has 1 row, the min and max will be the same, hence the difference will be 0 and the result of that query will be `0 / 0`, which MySQL translates into `NULL`.

If you prefer something else to be displayed instead of `NULL`, you can use a `coalesce` function

```
select  MO, PiID, Part_Number,
        count(*) as CNT,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                      min(Timestamp),
                      max(Timestamp)
                     ) / (count(*) - 1) as Average_Time,
        COALESCE(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
                               min(Timestamp),
                               max(Timestamp)
                              ) / (count(*) - 1),
                'something_else') as Average_Time_Coalesced
from    datalog
group by MO, PiID, Part_Number
```

Comment: You don't need at least two rows to compute an average.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen correct, but you do need two rows to calculate the average of a difference. I think we interpreted the requirement differently, you're returning the mid point while I return the average difference.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, they are asking for the average time for each *period* rather at each *point* in time.  You need two points in time to calculate the length of that period.  This is why with just one point in time their formula would return a division by zero error.

Comment: @Stefano Zanini   Thanks for helping. I did the SQL without `having  count(*) > 1` because I still want the record to print out. And there is a `NULL` inside the box. Will that cause problem?

Comment: @Doggy No, if you're fine with having `NULL` there won't be any issue. I edited my answer with a bit of explaination of why you're getting that value by the way.

Comment: Thanks for all the helps! Solved my problem.  : )